# Access: Sum values from multiple and variable columns

Tags: ms-access, vba

In `table1`, I have the field `Pianificato` and a lot of columns with name `Wxx_yyyy`.

I need to update `Table1.Pianificato` as sum of all the W-columns that satisfy a certain criteria.

The criteria that I should apply, is that xx is higher than a certain value.

In this example, xx > 2. So `Table1.W01_2018` and `Table1.W02_2018` will not be considered in the sum.

I don't think that this complex request can be satisfied by a Query. So I think the only way is VBA.

[image]

Comment: As I'm sure you realise this data structure is not normalised, it looks straight out of a spreadsheet. If the data was normalised this would be trivial, but as you have correctly stated you can't do this without using a function VBA loop.

Comment: I agree, since any calculation in query would likely be too long an expression, a VBA function called by query would be needed. Alternatively, if you have no more than 50 data columns, a UNION query could rearrange the fields to normalized structure. Then use the UNION query in an aggregate query. However, an aggregate query cannot be used in an UPDATE action query. But should not be saving this calculated data anyway, calculate when needed. Why would W02_2018 not be included, it has value >2?

Comment: @Minty yes, a VBA loop is the way. In order to simplify the code, I don't know if it better to "simulate" SQL code in the VBA code or just apply for/while statements. Any suggestion?

Comment: @June7 I agree: defenetly a VBA code is the way. The problem is that I don't know how to simulate UNION and UPDATE in this case because the for statement should be by row and by column. Some clues? Ps. "02" is equal to 2, so W02_2018 is not included because xx should be higher and not equal to 2.

Comment: Oh, you mean xx in the field name, not data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid VBA and there are no more than 50 Wxx fields, a UNION can rearrange fields. There should be a unique identifier field - an autonumber will serve. Since I suspect there are 52 Wxx fields and you don't want W01_2018 and W02_2018 fields, exclude those 2.

```
SELECT ID, W03_2018 AS Data, "W03_2028" AS WkYr FROM tablename
UNION SELECT ID, W04_2018, "W04_2018" FROM tablename
. . . 
UNION SELECT ID, W52_2018, "W52_2018" FROM tablename;
```

Then use that query in an aggregate query:

`SELECT ID, Sum(Data) AS Planificato FROM UnionQuery GROUP BY ID;`

Issue arises when you want to do calculations for a different set of weeks and/or year - have to modify the UNION.

A VBA approach may be more desirable, like:

```
Sub CalcPlanificato()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngP As Long, x As Integer

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1;")
While Not rs.EOF
    For x = 3 To 52
        lngP = lngP + rs.Fields(x)
    Next
    rs.Edit
    rs!Planificato = lngP
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
    lngP = 0
Wend

End Sub
```

Code assumes fields are in order in table as shown in example. Assumes Planificato is the first field. Assumes there are 52 Wxx fields. Wxx fields are referenced by index and W03_2018 is in column 4 which is index 3.